# Getting the PID of all running processes in Linux using a driver

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to do the extra exercise at [Kernel labs](https://linux-kernel-labs.github.io/refs/heads/master/labs/kernel_modules.html#ps-module). The problem presented is to print the PID and name of all running processes by writing a linux driver.

My approach is to work my way back to the `init` process by recursively using the pointer to `real_parent` in `task_struct`. This part works fine. But when I try to get the PID of the children processes I get strange values.

Here is part of the definition of `task_struct` in `linux/sched.h` that I am looking at (kernel version is 5.14.10).

```
    /* Real parent process: */
    struct task_struct __rcu    *real_parent;

    /* Recipient of SIGCHLD, wait4() reports: */
    struct task_struct __rcu    *parent;

    /*
     * Children/sibling form the list of natural children:
     */
    struct list_head        children; //I am trying to get the task_struct of the child process using this list_head
    struct list_head        sibling;
    struct task_struct      *group_leader;
```

Here is what I wrote to get the pid of the first and last child process:

```
    struct task_struct *child;
    struct task_struct *parent;
    struct task_struct *init;

    p = current;
    pr_info("Current process name %s\t", p->comm);
    pr_info("Current process id %d\n", p->pid);

    /* Get the *task_struct for init process. Print for debugging*/
    parent = p->real_parent;
    do {
        pr_info("Parent process name: %s, ", parent->comm);
        pr_info("Parent process id: %d\n", parent->pid);
        if (parent->pid == 1) {
            init = parent;
            break;
        }
        else {
            parent = parent->real_parent;
        }
    } while (1);

    /* Print some child processes of the init process */
    pr_info("list_next_entry pid: %d\n", list_next_entry(init, children)->pid);
    printk("list_first_entry pid = %d\n", list_first_entry(&init->children, struct task_struct, children)->pid);
    printk("list_last_entry pid = %d\n", list_last_entry(&init->children, struct task_struct, children)->pid);
```

And here is the output after insmodding the driver:

```
Current process name insmod
Current process id 336
Parent process name: sh,
Parent process id: 308
Parent process name: init, 
Parent process id: 1
list_next_entry pid: 2096789597
list_first_entry pid = 2096789597
list_last_entry pid = 1863549922
```

What am I doing wrong ? Also if there is a better approach please let me know.

Comment: list_next_entry is not for rcu lists

Comment: @stark How do I determine if a list item is RCU ?

Answer (score 0):

So the correct way to do it was using the `for_each_process(p)` macro in linux/sched/signal.h

```
for_each_process(p) {
        pr_info("Process name: %s, PID: %d\n", p->comm, p->pid);
}
```

Comment: Where do you see that called in the kernel that is not holding rcu_read_lock?  I don't see any locking in your code.

Comment: @start I did not know it had to be locked.